# Android Studio code doesn't work on Android Version P .CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android

My Android App works well in any android app version but doesn't work on *Android 9.0* but works under and more than 9.0?? There is an error displayed when I run the code from android studio on emulator the errors is:

> ```
> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
> ```

I try every close like `try{}` and not working.

My code of `autocompletetextview` is:

```
 AutoCompleteTextView srch_txt=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.srch_txt);

        db = new DBConnection(this);
        SQLiteDatabase dbb = db.getWritableDatabase();//connect to MyDB
        //
        final String [] mydata;
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        //Inside the method you've read the cursor, loop through it and add those item to array
        String sql="SELECT * FROM revuesC";
        //execute SQL
        Cursor cr= dbb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        cr.moveToFirst();//cursor pointing to first row
        mydata = new String[cr.getCount()];//create array string based on numbers of row
        int i=0;
        do  {
            mydata[i] = cr.getString(1) ;
            i++;
        }while(cr.moveToNext());
        //Finally Set the adapter to AutoCompleteTextView like this,
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mydata);
        //populate the list to the AutoCompleteTextView controls
        srch_txt.setAdapter(ad);
        cr.close();
```

Comment: cr.getCount()==0  Dont continue if so.

Comment: @ blackapps more explanation pls.

Comment: if (cr.getCount() <= 0) return;

Comment: @ blackapps it work thanks.